# Rotate svg in place using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to rotate a svg element with content using d3.js but it always gets out from the viewbox, what i want to achieve is rotate svg in place then later i can rotate the svg to `0,90,180,270deg` but for now my goal is to rotate it in place.

My code is below ( i removed the irrelevant codes)

```
 var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")                                          
                    .attr("width",121)                                   
                    .attr("height", 108)
               //below is my code to rotate the svg
                attr('transform', 'rotate(180 0 0)')
```

My original svg

[image]

My output when putting `attr('transform', 'rotate(180 0 0)')`

[image]

What i want to achieve

[image]

My fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ewumar8d/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rotate the svg about its center and not 0,0.

So first you will need to add a group to the svg like this:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 121 + "mm")
.attr("height", 108 + "mm")
.attr('id','board') 
.style('background','#f4f4f4')
.style("border", "1px solid black").append("g");//add agroup
```

To this group add all your data points.

Next in order to rotate we need find the center about which we need to rotate.

```
            svgContainer.attr('transform',function(){
                var me = svgContainer.node()
                var x1 = me.getBBox().x + me.getBBox().width/2;//the center x about which you want to rotate
                var y1 = me.getBBox().y + me.getBBox().height/2;//the center y about which you want to rotate

                return `rotate(180, ${x1}, ${y1})`;//rotate 180 degrees about x and y
            });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x6bj558v/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   .attr('transform', 'rotate(180 0 0)')
```

Comment: I tried your code but the rotation is off, i already updated my question, i think the following zeros `0` on rotate is what i need to figure out.